# Lithuanian citizen living and doing business on Reunion Island

Tags: france, eu-citizens

Lithuanian citizen living and doing business on the Reunion Island? How about an internet mail order business from there? Is it reasonably possible?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Logistics? Immigration? technical possiblity?

Comment: Exactly, all three.

Comment: Then: off-topic, possibly on topic but more details needed, off-topic, so can you edit your question.

Comment: What are you talking about? My question is very clear and, yes, I would like to know about logistics, which means shipping light goods from Ile de Reunion to the rest of the world via speed couriers, such as UPS and FedEx and the local post office service (probably France Post), moving (immigration if you can call it that way), which is probably not a problem and the other one is not exactly a technical possibility issue, but rather a question how the locals in the Reunion treat foreigners that are not native French speakers.

Comment: The question as it stands is unclear the logistics of running the business as well as technical possibility is off topic for this forum.  And if you are asking about immigration question related to starting a business on Reunion Island then clarify it and move on.  And insulting someone isn't helping your case any.  Plus the character you're referring to has 2 s in his name.  But ignorance is bliss I suppose.

Comment: @John please edit your question and add the relevant parts from your comment there

Answer (score 2):

John,

Have you ever visited Réunion Island?
Internet is not an issue here in Réunion, but have you already checked out the cost of sending parcels from Réunion via speed couriers and La Poste? You'll find it's more expensive from Réunion than from mainland France or Lithuania. And where will what you'll be sending come from? Will you be making it yourself or importing it? Where will the items and/or raw material come from? And for example from Réunion you can't post anything non-urgent abroad via sea any more, it has to go via airmail whether you like it or not. Price lists for all this are available online or on request if you e-mail those concerned, but this brings us to another part of your question: language. You don't say whether you don't speak French or whether you speak it but just not as a native speaker. If you don't speak French you will have a hard time getting by professionally as everything here is in French. If you do speak fluent French, even with a (understandable) foreign accent, you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I will be fine with Air Mail and FEDEX-UPS. Would be mailing to and from the entire world. My French is not fluent at all, so I may have to spend another couple years to better it, but the problem is, not living among the French is hard to learn the language more fluently. Most important so that the local community does not reject a newcomer, like they do in some countries outside of big cities such as in the USA, with tricks created to kill you. Example, an evil electrician. Very serious stuff. Will visit Reunion soon; looking to buy an estate there. Expat.

Comment: The local community won't reject a newcomer, Réunion is a melting pot and fairly tolerant of 'outsiders', but when it comes to dealing with French administration and bureaucracy which you'll have to do if you're setting up and running a business (fluent) French is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Legally speaking, Réunion is part of the European Union. It's out of the Schengen area, which makes a difference for citizens from non-EU countries but apart from that all the usual rules apply, including the freedom of establishment. Just as in mainland France, you are expected to conduct all official business in French but it's not especially difficult to get set-up if you do.

Beyond that, as @champacs explained, shipping is generally expensive so it does not seem to be a very attractive base of operation for a mail-order business, all other things being equal.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I am used to 100€+ charges to ship documents via FEDEX from remote oceanic islands. Learning French fluently will have to be done living among the French. First few years will be tough I guess. I like exotic locations; want to grow some exotic plants over there that do not grow in European climates. Merci beaucoup.